# Something about header() and security of forms

Tags: php, forms, security, header

I'm building a login system and I'm also looking to make it a little more secure.
I won't post my whole login process file as it's not done yet but I do need a short to-do-style list to make the whole system more secure. I know using PDO's prepared statements helps against SQL injections. I'm obviously also hashing the password with a salt. Is there anything else that's critical?
Would really help me!

I also read somewhere that using `header()` is not recommended in forms. (for example: to redirect a user after the registration process is done.)
Is this true or not? And what are some other alternatives?

By the way, the form data will be processed in another page obviously, and I was wondering if it's possible to send back errors from the process file (e.g "The username is too short"). I know it's easily doable with jQuery's `.post()` and the callback function but I'm just curious :D

Comment: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/73024/what-best-practices-should-be-employed-in-a-php-login-script

Comment: Thank you. I'm going to try and implant bcrypt in my code. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's my suggestion about login system:

- store user's ID in cookie
- generate special token and hash+salt and store them in cookies
- store everything in database
- get data from cookies on every page load and try searching for them in database
- if not found, then logout a user
- change token on every page load

You can use `header()` to redirect user, but also use `die()` or `exit()` after it, because if you don't use one of them, a rest of your code will continue execution.

Comment: ...if the user disables cookies?

Comment: Exactly... Also, wouldn't using `session_regenerate_id()` count as renewing a token? and what exactly should I hash+salt? Just a random string and set it as a token? Thanks!

Comment: @MrD It's good idea to use the combination of cookies and session

Comment: @xTCx I'm not sure, but what I think Nikola is referring to with 'token' is similar to a nonce.. just a unique sequence of characters that gets regenerated on each page load.  Forms send it from the client side via hidden inputs and you validate against the form submission on the server-side, ie `if($_POST['nonce'] != $_SESSION['nonce']) { // invalid form submission...`

Comment: But nonces are mostly used to forbid people without permissions to preform an action, don't they? or am I wrong? couldn't get my hands on a good tutorial to be honest...

Answer (score 1):

Sure, you can send back errors.  For example, if you have

```
<form method="post" action="action.php">
  <input type="text" name="username" />
</form>
```

then in action.php, when checking for length of `$_POST['username']`, if it's too short, do something like

```
 print('<p class="warnings">The username is too short; it must be between X and Y characters.</p>');
 require('yourform.php');
```

where `yourform.php` contains the HTML for the form above.

Comment: Thanks. I'm assuming the above error will show in the very beginning of the page, won't it? Is there a way to put it wherever I want it logically?

Comment: Where it appears on the page is determined by where you actually `print` the error message in your php script (e.g. "action.php"). You can have it then before or after your form, your choice.

Comment: Ok thanks I got it. I think it'd be easier to use jquery ajax call which gives me the simplicity of choosing where to place my errors more specifically.